# How to get knowledgeArtcticleVersion and knowledgeArticle objects with soql

Tags: soql, knowledge

I need to retrieve the knowledgeArtcticleVersion and the knowledgeArticle objects. I only have a list of caseArticle to start. So I try somethinf like that:

```
List<CaseArticle> lCaseArt = [SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId FROM CaseArticle WHERE CaseId =: pCaseId];

    List<Id> sIdKnowledgeArt = new List<Id>();
    for(CaseArticle ca : lCaseArt){
        sIdKnowledgeArt.add(ca.KnowledgeArticleId);
    }
 List<KnowledgeArticle> lKnowledgeArt = [SELECT Id
                                            FROM KnowledgeArticle 
                                            WHERE Id IN :sIdKnowledgeArt];

List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> lKnowledgeArtVersion = [SELECT Id
                                                FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
                                                WHERE KnowledgeArticleId IN :sIdKnowledgeArt];
```

Here when I compile I got this error, about the last query :

> Implementation restriction: When querying or searching the KnowledgeArticleVersion object, you must filter using the following syntax: Id = [single ID], Id IN [list of ID's] or PublishStatus = [status]. In addition PublishStatus is only permitted in a top-level AND condition.

I don't see what I am doing wrong. But to be honest I don't really see how I can retrive the knowledgeArtcticleVersion and the knowledgeArticle objects and if I can do a nested query betwwen them (I try this too, but got an error, so I try to do 2 differents queries)

Answer (score 1):

As your error message clearly mention and also stated in docs:

> Querying or searching articles in SOQL or SOSL requires that you
>   specify either the PublishStatus or the Id field in the WHERE clause.

So you need to add `PublishStatus` in your second query as well.

[KnowledgeArticleVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm)